# Validating and unzipping a zip file in AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Requirement states that the lambda function must check the zipfile for any excluded file extensions which have been defined in the function.
I have outlined the steps which are needed for a successful run.

1. I need to validate it and make sure that the zip file doesn't have the bad extensions. This step seems to be running and the validation is being run.
2. The file needs to be unzipped.
3. The file should be unzipped in an 'unzipped' folder in the same directory.

All the above steps are occurring but I seem to be getting an attribute error in my code which has been outlined below. Any ideas/ solutions are greatly appreciated.

```
import json
import zipfile
import os
import boto3
from urllib.parse import unquote_plus
import io
import re
import gzip



exclude_list = [".exe", ".scr", ".vbs", ".js", ".xml", "docm", ".xps"]
sns = boto3.client('sns' )


def read_nested_zip(tf, bucket, key, s3_client):
        print(key)
        print ("search for.zip:",re.search(r'\.zip', key, re.IGNORECASE))
        ## need to add exception handling
        ##if re.search(r'\.gzip$', key, re.IGNORECASE):
          ##  print ('gzip file found')
        ##    fil = gzip.GzipFile(tf, mode='rb')
        if re.search(r'\.zip$', key, re.IGNORECASE):
            print ('zip file found')
            fil = zipfile.ZipFile(tf, "r").namelist()
        else:
            fil = ()
            print ('no file found')
        print (fil)
        ##with fil as zipf:
            ##try to narrow scope - run loop else exit
        for file in fil:
            print(file)
            if re.search(r'(\.zip|)$', file, re.IGNORECASE):
                childzip = io.BytesIO(fil.read(file))
                read_nested_zip(childzip, bucket, key, s3_client)
            else:
                if any(x in file.lower() for x in exclude_list):
                    print("Binary, dont load")
                    print(file)
                    print(bucket)
                    print(key)
                    env = bucket.split('-')[2].upper()
                    # Copy the parent zip to a separate folder and remove it from the path
                    copy_source = {'Bucket': bucket, 'Key': key}
                    s3_client.copy_object(Bucket=bucket, CopySource=copy_source, Key='do_not_load_'+key)
                    s3_client.delete_object(Bucket = bucket, Key = key)
                    sns.publish(
                        TopicArn = 'ARN',
                        Subject = env + ': S3 upload warning: Non standard File encountered ',
                        Message = 'Non standard File encountered' + key + ' uploaded to bucket ' + bucket + ' The file has been moved to ' + 'do_not_load_'+key
                        )
                else:
                    print("File in supported formats, can be loaded " + file)
                    #folder = re.sub(r"\/[^/]+$", "",key)
                    folder = "/".join(key.split("/", 2)[:2]) + "/unzipped"
                    print(folder)
                    print("Bucket is "+ bucket)
                    print("file to copy is "+ file)
                    buffer = io.BytesIO(fil.read(file))
                    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
                    s3_resource.meta.client.upload_fileobj(buffer,Bucket=bucket,Key= folder + '/' + file)
                    s3_resource.Object(bucket, folder + '/' + file).wait_until_exists()
                
    


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    for record in event['Records']:
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
        key = unquote_plus(record['s3']['object']['key'])
        print(key)
        print (type(key))
        size = record['s3']['object']['size']
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        print(obj)
        putObjects = []
        with io.BytesIO(obj["Body"].read()) as tf:
            # rewind the file
            #tf.seek(0)
            read_nested_zip(tf, bucket, key, s3_client)
```

Error code"[ERROR] AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 85, in lambda_handler
    read_nested_zip(tf, bucket, key, s3_client)
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 35, in read_nested_zip
    childzip = io.BytesIO(fil.read())

Things I tried:
1.

```
childzip = io.BytesIO(fil.read(file))
#tried switching the childzip = io.BytesIO(fil.read()) #still failed
```

2. 

```
changed
childzip = io.BytesIO(fil)
[ERROR] AttributeError: module 'zipfile' has no attribute 'read'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 85, in lambda_handler
    read_nested_zip(tf, bucket, key, s3_client)
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 25, in read_nested_zip
    fil = zipfile.read(tf, "r").namelist()
```

Any ideas are appreciated. Best

Comment: Did you mean to call `fil.read(file)`? Apparently `fil` is a list.

Comment: @jarmod Yes I did. I wanted to read all the files in the zip file.

Comment: Not sure I'd be using the node-zipfile package. It's quite old and the documentation is weak. Your code sets `fil = zipfile.ZipFile(tf, "r").namelist()` which is presumably a list, hence not the zipfile object that you thought it was, hence `.read()` is not valid.

Comment: @jarmod would setting fil = zipfile.read() to read the names of the files be a better option?

Comment: @jarmod I changed the fil variable to set it to read the zip file but I received the same attribute error. 
```
[ERROR] AttributeError: module 'zipfile' has no attribute 'read'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 85, in lambda_handler
    read_nested_zip(tf, bucket, key, s3_client)
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 25, in read_nested_zip
    fil = zipfile.read(tf, "r").namelist()
```

Comment: Which documentation are you using? I now think you're using the [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) module. It has examples of some of the methods.

Comment: @jarmod I am using the zipfile module you linked above. I am using the zipfile.read method to try and read the file name

Answer (score 0):

As long as the ZIP file is not too big, I'd suggest downloading the ZIP file to the Lambda function's `/tmp` folder and then using the zipfile context manager to simplify accessing the ZIP file. Alternatively, you can stream the ZIP file but probably still use the context manager.

Note that I've included code that specifically reads the byte content of a file from within the ZIP file. See `bytes = myzip.read(name)` below.

For example:

```
import json
import os
import zipfile
import boto3
from urllib.parse import unquote_plus

ZIP_NAME = "/tmp/local.zip"
EXCLUDE_LIST = [".exe", ".scr", ".vbs", ".js", ".xml", "docm", ".xps"]
s3 = boto3.client("s3")


def process_zip(bucket, key):
    s3.download_file(bucket, key, ZIP_NAME)
            
    with zipfile.ZipFile(ZIP_NAME, "r") as myzip:
        namelist = myzip.namelist()
        for name in namelist:
            print("Zip contains:", name)

        extensions = [os.path.splitext(name)[1] for name in namelist]
        print("Extensions:", extensions)

        if any(extension in EXCLUDE_LIST for extension in extensions):
            print("Banned extensions present in:", extensions)
            os.remove(ZIP_NAME)
            return

        for name in namelist:
            print("Zip read:", name)
            bytes = myzip.read(name)
            # your code here ...

    os.remove(ZIP_NAME)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for record in event.get("Records", []):
        key = unquote_plus(record["s3"]["object"]["key"])
        bucket = record["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]

        if os.path.splitext(key)[1] == ".zip":
            process_zip(bucket, key)

    return {"statusCode": 200, "body": json.dumps("OK")}
```